# Browser error: PrimeFacesExt is not defined

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Im using PrimeFaces 3.5 with PrimeFaces Extensions 0.7.0 and OmniFaces version 1.4

I have a accordionPanel with a ui:fragment witch looks like that:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"> 
<ui:fragment>

    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent" listener="#{fleet.preRenderView()}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <!-- Other things.... -->

    <!-- Dialogs -->
    <p:dialog id="createSubFleetDialog" widgetVar="createSubFleet"
        header="#{msg.administration_fleet_createFleetDialog_title}">
        <h:panelGrid id="createSubFleetPanel" columns="2">

            <!-- Here im using primefaces extensions -->

            <h:outputLabel for="newFleetName" value="#{msg.administration_fleet_fleetName}" />
            <p:inputText id="newFleetName" value="#{fleet.fleetName}">
                <pe:keyFilter mask="alphanum"></pe:keyFilter>
            </p:inputText>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>


</ui:fragment>
</html>
```

There is no warning or error in eclipse but when running my application there is a browser error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFacesExt is not defined**

Does anybody know how how to fix this problem?

Comment: I have same issue here with ext 2.1 and 3.0 , I have pe:inputNumber, did you figured out what the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was have same issue, but i found working workaround for it in this link : http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=36652

Seems the issue is :

> It seems primefaces ext js files are not loaded unless we use at least
>   one ext tag.
>
> Since i was not using one on the main page..but it was in a dynamic
>   ui:include, it was loading only after a hard refresh of main page.

So you can add dummy pe tag in your main template just after `<h:body>` like this :

```
<pe:blockUI></pe:blockUI>
```

Or like :

```
<pe:inputNumber style="display:none" />
```

Its worked for me actually.

Answer (score 2):

Facing this issue, we found that a cleaner fix was to simply add this line in the `<h:head>` tag in the main template:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces-extensions" name="primefaces-extensions.js"/>
```

No need to add the `xmlns:pe` namespace, no need to add a dummy tag!